# Set state and change local variable while ESLint is preventing to do

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle, state-management

I am using `ESlint` in my react project.

I have to update **states** and **local variable**s when `props` are updated.

`ESlint` and `React` ask me not to use `setState` in:

- `componentDidMount`
- `componentWillUpdate`
- `componentDidUpdate`
- `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`

I can use only `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update `state`, but I can't use it to use and update local variables.

And I can use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to update state and local variables but it doesn't update them in the first loaded.

Is there any good solution to update them?

Comment: Syncing props and local state is generally considered an anti-pattern. You would rather use a state management system like redux, to sync your "states". Could you maybe elaborate more on the actual problem you're trying to fix, since syncing the state like you're planning to, will quickly become a pain in the ass.

Comment: Well, `nextProps` are from `mobx` store. I have to init and update `highcharts` and its controllers (`zoom in/out `: they are `state` values) when `props` are changed.

Comment: I agree with @TobiasTengler , please explain why you need to use props to update local state because there is a fair chance there is a better way

Comment: I agree with TobiasTengler and ChrisSandvik. Usually I find SO questions too detailed, but in this one the context is required